# What is the Lifetime of variables Stored in Factory -- Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I was wondering what is the lifetime of variables stored in factory/services in Angular JS? If we refresh the page, will the values still persist? What will happen if we refresh the entire application? Actually i am trying to store values in factory and fetch them on any page by passing them in respective controllers. So should we refresh (F5) the pplication, will values go undefined in factory?
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Share some snippet .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifetime of a service is the lifetime of the application - services are basically Singletons, created when the application is constructed.

So you basically ask: what actions restart the application?

The user manually 'refreshing' the page: yes. The browser takes the user's request literally: discard the current page and reload it (although of course there are caching issues to think about; but they are separte from the lifetime of any javascript objects).

The application navigating to a URL in the same namespace (i.e., the part of the URL before '/#/'): no. Whatever routes you set up (e.g., '/#/foo/page1') and then navigate to under code control do not trigger the browser to reload the page. The original application object (and thus the Singletons that represent services) remain active.

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific about the last 2 sentences? if i can have more insight on that

Comment: I added a little more detail.